# how to call web service rest based using ajax + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling web service on this url .

here is my code .

http://jsfiddle.net/LsKbJ/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //event handler for submit button
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        //collect userName and password entered by users
        var userName = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        //call the authenticate function
        authenticate(userName, password);
    });
});

//authenticate function to make ajax call
function authenticate(userName, password) {
    $.ajax({
        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
        url: "",
        type: "POST",
        // dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        //json object to sent to the authentication url
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Ticket: 'Some ticket',
            Data: {

                Password: "1",
                Username:"aa"
            }
        }),
        success: function (t) {
            alert(t+"df")
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert(data+"dfdfd")
        }
    })
}
```

Response
**

**

It mean that I first call this method then call login method ?

Comment: (-1) for downvoting good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the message means that during development, while you are writing and testing the code, use the URL:

`http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronServiceAppleDemoIndia/REST/GetNewAuthentifikationTicket`

rather than:

`http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronService/REST/Login`

Because you don't need the application id for the development method. You can see from the error message that you are missing the `application (gu)id`

`The guid '61136208-742B-44E4-B00D-C32ED26775A3' is no valid application guid`

Comment: Can you please tell me what are parameters used in this functionGetNewAuthentifikationTicket

Comment: Look for the section heading: "The following is an example request Json body:" and follow the example. Perhaps the "application" parameter is disregarded, perhaps it should have a "null" value. You may want to contact someone for more documentation, and examples.

Comment: I won't be offering any more advice since you already downvoted my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your javascript needs to be updated to use new url `http://isuite.c-entron.de/CentronServiceAppleDemoIndia/GetNewAuthentifikationTicket` as per the backend sode team.

Also, even if you do this, your will not be able to get reply correctly since service requires cross domain configuration entries in web.config. You have to use this reference:http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/ and configure server's web.config in a way so that you can call it from cross domain.